# Doctrine2 - annotations vs yml / xml

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

What's the plus side of annotations for entity description in Doctrine2?

In Doctrine1 & Propel (which I've used many times), reverse-engineering a database to create yml or xml, then generating the model is a very quick workflow.

In Doctrine2, choosing annotations, one must write a large amount of boiler plate code just to get the entities in place..; yet annotations seem to be the 'way to go'.

What am I missing?

Comment: One of the reasons that Doctrine2 is great is that the domain model does not necessarily have to correspond to the database model. Doctrine 1 is much more intrusive in this sense, since it forces your models to inherit from Doctrine_Record, and your repositories from Doctrine_Table. If you use Symfony2 you get a lot of help with generating entities though, and it also gives you the option to select whether you want to use the XML, YAML or Annotation mapping format. This leaves you to only have to define the relationships between your entities.

Comment: I have gotten the sense that the model is actually much less coupled to the schema itself.  I used sf a lot previously, but am ramping up on ZF now, so for the moment it's the zf 1.x / Doctrine2 combo.  The extra support from sf2 comes as no surprise though; I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The workflow you describe from D1 and propel is exactly the opposite of the preferred way of thinking for Doctrine2.  In fact, I avoided writing my own database definitions in D1 as well, for mostly the same reasons I give here:

In Doctrine 2, you are concerned first-and-foremost with your entities.  Entities are just plain PHP object, and doctrine just handles your persistence. The fact that Doctrine is there behind the scenes squirreling data away in some database is an practically an afterthought.  All of that mess is exactly what you're supposed to be abstracting away!  In theory, you could get rid of doctrine at some future date, and write your own persistence logic.   Your entities would still work just like they always have.

Looking at it that way, starting with a database schema is downright silly.  You're more interested in your entities and the business logic embedded in and around them.  That's tasty soup!

Now, since you're using doctrine for persistence of your entities, it (probably) makes sense to keep your mapping data right there with the class definitions.

So your new workflow is:

1. Design some entities by defining some plain-vanilla PHP classes.
2. Mark the class definitions up with some fancy comments for doctrine
   to chew on.
3. `./doctrine orm:schema:create` and let doctrine worry about the
   database table definitions.

Now, if you have some legacy database, things get trickier and a lot less fun.  I've not really dealt with that scenario with D2, but I imagine it's ugly.

**Regarding Boilerplate code:** I see people complain about having to write getters/setters for their entities.  I do something similar [what this guy does](http://epixa.com/2010/05/the-best-models-are-easy-models.html) - all my entities extend an AbstractEntity class which uses magic methods to generate getters/setters for any properties that don't have hand-crafted ones.  Once you do that, there's practically no boiler-plate to be had.

Alternatively, there are plenty of tools these days that will stamp out the boilerplate for you (PHPStorm does this, plugins for Sublime, etc).  This makes the boiler-plate fairly painless, and comes with the additional advantage that you can add type-hints, and your editor can provide useful auto-completion.

Comment: Great response.  I'm adjusting to the new workflow you outline here, but one drawback, and I am whining a little bit here, is the time to get off the ground.  I could write the schema in SQL, generate XML / yml and a model in a fraction of the time.  Then I'm off to the domain logic, promptly.  I understand there are drawbacks in terms of flexibility.  I've also considered a base class like you mention, but all that magic is a bit slow :D  I may end up doing it for time sake though.  I'll have a closer look at this example base class when I get back to the code.

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, you'll find it's a pretty fast workfow.  All your work lives in one place, and you just hammer on orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql (or --force).  Once you've got the various annotation directives committed to memory, work goes fast.  RE: magic methods, you can always go back and hand-craft setters/getters  if you ever need to optimize.  In most cases, you never will.

Comment: True, true, but another benefit of actually stamping the functions into the entities besides the (small :)) performance benefit is seeing the methods in generated documentation like doxygen or phpDocumentor.  I'm def using the base class to get through the first phase of writing the entities for sure though.

Comment: True, magic methods make generated docs or IDE autocomplete less useful.  You can add annotations with @method to your class docs, which documentation tools and IDEs will use ( see http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html), but at that point you might as well just stamp out boring methods.

Comment: It seems that the link @timdev posted no longer works. Just wanted to post an updated link for everyone. http://epixa.com/2010/05/the-best-models-are-easy-models.html

Comment: @jayem - thanks, I've updated the answer with the updated link.

Comment: Magic methods are not always nice.. with MM you loose the type-hinting ability for the non-basic parameter types. Like classes, arrays and datetimes.. Making code much much less readable. I prefer to use the sublime extension that generates getters and setters for the attributes.

Comment: @KnF - Indeed.  I switched over to having PHPStorm stamp out accessors and mutators several years ago.

Comment: As for **Boilerplate Getters/Setter**, try **ALT+INS** in your IDE, the chances are it'll create them for you with 2 clicks.

Answer (score 10):

The main reason I use annotations over either yml or xml is ease of configuration. I don't have to look in another file to remember (for instance) what I set the join table name as in a ManyToMany relationship. And if I change something in a domain object (which happens a lot early in my development process), I don't have to remember to update another configuration file with the changes as well.

However, as you said, a database schema ports more easily to one of the other configuration formats, so in situations like this, you may indeed be better off using yml or xml instead of annotations. It all comes down to personal preference in the end... use whatever you're most comfortable with.

Comment: I posted on [doctrine-user](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/400074d9b1999821) and got a similar response.  Seems worth it to stick with annotations on at least one project in order to obtain an objective opinion.  The first leg of the journey will involve a lot of boilerplate coding tho :D